# jsTree AJAX Lazy Loading search with node childs?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have a Jstree with Version 3.0 that I make and have a search Field. My Tree uses Lazy Loading. I try to make a Search but it doesn't work.

- Here is my Jstree Configuration with the Search Plugin

```js
var init_tree = function() {

    $('#container').jstree({
         'plugins': ['search'],
        'core': {
            'data': {
                'url': "wwv_flow.show",
                "dataType": "json",
                'data': function(node) {
                    var v_node_id;
                    if ($(node).attr("id") == '#') {
                        v_node_id = 0;
                    } else {
                        v_node_id = $(node).attr("id");
                    }
                    
                    return {
                        "p_request": "APPLICATION_PROCESS=GET_NODE_DATAA",
                        "p_flow_id": $v('pFlowId'),
                        "p_flow_step_id": $v('pFlowStepId'),
                        "p_instance": $v('pInstance'),
                        "x01": v_node_id,
                        "x02": "LOADA"

                    };
                },
                "success": function(new_data) {
                    return new_data;
                }
            }
        },
    'search': {
        'case_insensitive': true,
        'show_only_matches' : true,
        'fuzzy' : false,
        
            'ajax' : {
            "dataType": "json",
            "url"            : apex.server.url ({p_request: "APPLICATION_PROCESS=PATA",x01: $("#P27_SEARCH").val() })
         }   
    }
   
    }).on('search.jstree', function (nodes, str, res) {
    if (str.nodes.length===0) {
$('#container').jstree(true).hide_all();
    }
})

};
```

- Here is the Search of the Jstree when enter some Data

```js
$('#P27_SEARCH').keyup(function(){
  $('#container').jstree(true).show_all();
  //$('#container').jstree('search', $(this).val());
  $('#container').jstree(true).search($(this).val(), false, true, 'root1');
});
```

- Here is the Output for data coming for the Server when perform a Search

```json
["n1114714", "n1114898", "n1114963", "n1115149",
 "n1115504", "n1117568", "n1118202", "n1118267",
 "n1118453", "n1118808", "n1171451", "n1171635",
 "n1171700", "n1171886", "n1172241", "n627355",
 "n631173", "n631598", "n631634", "n631635",
 "n631645"]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for help